# Powershell Loading Binary Module

Tags: powershell

I have few powershell script which I am trying to put into module. In the same module I also intend to load a c# dll for token generation. DLL uses System.Management.Automation.

[image]

```
#content of asr.psm1
Import-Module ".\tokengenerator\PowershellTokenGenerator.dll"
Get-ChildItem $psscriptroot\*.ps1 -Recurse | ForEach-Object { . $_.FullName }
```

The folder tokengenerator includes dll to generate OAuth2.0 token. How can I load powershell module and C# cmdlet under the same module. However, when I am trying to load the module I get the below error.

```
Import-Module D:\repo\src\aadsr\setup\asr.psm1

Import-Module : The specified module '.\tokengenerator\PowershellTokenGenerator.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At D:\repo\src\aadsr\setup\asr.psm1:1 char:1
+ Import-Module ".\tokengenerator\PowershellTokenGenerator.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (.\tokengenerato...enGenerator.dll:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: Is `PowershellTokenGenerator.dll` a PowerShell module?  `Import-Module` is only for importing PowerShell modules, not any old C# library.  Take a look at [Add-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6).

Comment: dll is binary powershell module

Comment: Does it load outside of your module?  i.e. if you open the console and just use `Import-Module` directly on the file, does it work? Also, is the DLL compiled for the same OS type as the version of PowerShell you are running (e.g. 64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\tokengenerator\PowershellTokenGenerator.dll"
```

to ensure that the DLL is found relative to the *script module's* (`*.psm1`) location, reflected in automatic variable `$PSScriptRoot`.

By contrast, if you use `Import-Module ".\..."`, the DLL is looked for relative to the *current location* (`.`), whatever it may be.